# Execute ui-sref based on watcher boolean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button (in section 1) that on click executes a function to update view before moving on to the next section (section 2).

```
<button ng-click="checkout.updateView(info)" ng-disabled="checkout.isUpdatingView" ui-sref="view.section2" class="layout__section1>
    <span ng-hide="checkout.isUpdatingView">Update and Continue</span>
    <span ng-show="checkout.isUpdatingView">Updating <span class="spinner"></span></span>
</button>
```

​It calls a function

```
vm.isUpdatingView = false;

function updateView(info) {
        vm.isUpdatingView = true;
        ..does some stuff and on success...
        vm.isUpdatingView = false;
}
```

The problem is this button on click directly goes to section 2 because of the `ui-sref`.. I need it to only go to section 2 after the view has been updated successfully. I want the spinner to be reflective of the `UpdatingView` process. How would I alter this so that `ui-sref` watches the change in `isUpdatingView` after it's been called and then calls section 2 if it's successful? I'm completely new to Angular so any other suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ui-sref` in the template, use `$state.go()` in the function. Just add

```
if(vm.isUpdatingView == true) {
    $state.go("view.section2"):
}
```

More info [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)